# Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'RootObject'

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am getting json in below mentioned format.

```
[{
    "count":"2",
    "data":[{
        "Name": "Pinky",
        "number": "91XXXX",
        "place": "Mumbai"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rohan",
        "number": "91XXXX",
        "place": "Pune"
    }]
}]
```

For practice,I have taken it into string like this

```
string json = "[{
    \"count\":\"2\",
    \"data\":[{
        \"Name\": \"Pinky\",
        \"number\": \"91XXXX\",
        \"place\": \"Mumbai\"
    },
    {
        \"Name\": \"Rohan\",
        \"number\": \"91XXXX\",
        \"place\": \"Pune\"
    }]
}]";
```

I have created a classes for that .

```
public class Datum
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string place { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string count { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

But when I am writing like this ,getting error.

```
RootObject cdr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Well yes, your JSON shows an array, but you're trying to deserialize to just a `RootObject`. Have you tried deserializing to a `List<RootObject>`?

Answer (score 2):

Your json is an array Use

```
var cdr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```